# Write to jTextArea from different class

Tags: java, swing, class, io, jtextarea

Just wondering if it is possible to append to a jTextArea in one class from a separate class? I basically have a simple class that is constantly running calculations and I want to view the output on a GUI which I have created in its own class. The program executes fine via System.out.println but I want to view this on my textarea now. Many thanks in advance for any guidance.

Updated - The code below is what I am running. The area in question is the following (This is a method from a rather large class) :

```
System.out.println("From Server:" + sentenceFromServer);
```

I want this output to be written to a seperate jTextArea which is in another class which is below the below class.

Client Class

```
public void run() {
   SocketForm form = new SocketForm();
    //File file=null;

  long startTime; // Starting time of program, in milliseconds.
  long endTime;   // Time when computations are done, in milliseconds.
  double time; 
  System.out.println("Variables Set");
  String serverName = "localhost";
   try {
    //if (args.length >= 1)
       // serverName = args[0];
  InetAddress serverIPAddress = InetAddress.getByName(serverName);

    //get server port;
    int serverPort = form.cliportNo;
    //if (args.length >= 2)
      //  serverPort = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    //create socket
    DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
    //get input from keybaord
    byte[] sendData = new byte[byteSize];
    //BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (System.in));
    //while (true){
    //String sentence = inFromUser.readLine();
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    //sendData = sentence.getBytes();
    System.out.println("About to identify image");
    String fileName = "/Users/Andrew/Desktop/pic.jpg";
    File f = new File(fileName);

    FileInputStream fis = null;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(f);
        System.out.println("Total file size to read in bytes is : " + fis.available());

    } catch (IOException e) {}


 Path path = Paths.get("/Users/Andrew/Desktop/pic.jpg");
 //byte[] data = Fles.readAllBytes(path);
  sendData = Files.readAllBytes(path);   

    try {
    for( int index = 0; index < sendData.length ; index += byteSize ) {
     DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket( sendData, index, Math.min( byteSize, sendData.length-index ), serverIPAddress, serverPort);
     clientSocket.send(packet);
    //DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, serverIPAddress, serverPort);

    //receive datagram
    byte[] receiveData = new byte [byteSize];

    DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
    clientSocket.receive(receivePacket);
    //print output
    String sentenceFromServer = new String(receivePacket.getData());
    System.out.println("From Server:" + sentenceFromServer);
    }
    System.out.println("The End");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {}
    //close client socket
            //clientSocket.close();
        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
  time = endTime - startTime;
      System.out.println("Time :" + time);
   // }
}
   catch (Exception e) {}
}
```

SocketForm Class (GUI)

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SocketForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEV
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new SocketForm().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.ButtonGroup buttonGroup1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
private javax.swing.JTabbedPane jTabbedPane1;
public static javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;

// End of variables declaration
```

}

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Perhaps you should show all relevant code.

Comment: Agree, this is absolutely possible. But given the limited information in your question, this is about all anyone can tell you. Try asking a better more complete question, one that gives us some chance of figuring out what might not be working right.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to display console output in java JTextarea one by one in a loop when button action is triggered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14357418/how-to-display-console-output-in-java-jtextarea-one-by-one-in-a-loop-when-button)

Comment: thanks for responses. Code now showing above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suggestions:

- Give the GUI class a public method, `public void appendText(String text)` that simply appends the text String to the JTextArea.
- Any outside class that wishes to append text to the JTextArea only needs to have a valid reference to the class that has this method, and then needs to call it.
- Care must be taken to be sure to only call this method on the Swing event thread, the EDT.
- Since you'll be doing this from a long-running bit of code, you'll want to do this long running code **off** of the Swing event thread. A SwingWorker will work well for this. Google and study the tutorial as it will be quite useful.
- You should consider specifically using a `SwingWorker<Void, String>` and use the publish/process method pair to send the String from the server to the JTextArea, on the Swing **E**vent **D**ispatch **T**hread or EDT.
- ***Never*** have an empty catch block as you show in your code above, `catch (IOException e) {}`. This is the coding equivalent of driving a motorcycle with your eyes closed. Yes, it might seem like fun at first, but it will almost always ends badly.

---

**Edit**
You state:

> "If it is as you say only suitable to run it on the EDT how can this be defined inside the thread which is already running?"

I know 2 ways:

1. Use a SwingWorker for the background thread, and use the publish/process method pair for this.  Check the SwingWorker tutorial as this is well described there, or
2. Use a standard background thread and put any Swing calls inside of a Runnable that you pass to the `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)` method.

Comment: hmmmm equivalent of driving a motorcycle with your eyes closed :-)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I have tried to run this on another thread as you suggested however still no joy. I have however created a test class and tried to append to the textarea from that class and it works perfectly. code used was simply        SocketForm.jTextField2.setText("Test"); It seems that this command will not run inside my thread in the client class. If it is as you say  only suitable to run it on the EDT how can this be defined inside the thread which is already running?

Comment: Thanks. I’ll have a crack at both.

Comment: Ive re written the code from the ground up and implemented the threading a bit better as well as some of the things you suggested. Seems to be purring away now. Many thanks for your help.